# How is proper way to repiar npm vulnarabilities in project?

Tags: npm, compiler-warnings, maintainability, npm-audit

How fixes the npm audit warnings [npm warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR06F.png). How is the best practice to repiar this?
I'm new in programming and this is my first question please understand and reply in detail :)

I trying npm audit fix --force but after this I have more warnings than before.
I try to eliminate all these warnings.